# Hartl Chap. 9.2.2 test fail

Tags: ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I am about to proceed to sec. 9.2.3 when all of the sudden my spec test turns to RED!!!!
what am i doing wrong?? Here are my errors:

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication authorization as wrong user visiting Users#edit page 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
       expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Edit user" not to return anything
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:72:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action 
     Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:77:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.57 seconds
64 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:72 # Authentication authorization as wrong user visiting Users#edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:77 # Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action
```

authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end

        it "should create a user" do
         expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
      specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

What could be the issue? The stuff is pretty much exactly what the tutorial calls for.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `edit` action to:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

And the first line in your `update` action should also do this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  ...
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Just to be clear, this should be in users_controller.rb

Comment: Updated for this.  You need to make sure you assign your instance variables before using them.

Comment: I did add the line to 'update'. I'm fairly new to this, so what do you mean when you say 'assign your instance variables'?

Comment: `@user` is an instance variable that is used by many of your views and most of your actions.  If you don't assign a value (`@user = something`), then calling it evaluates to `nil`.  Which means that calling `@user.some_method` is the equivalent of writing `nil.some_method`.  This is why you are getting 'undefined method for nil:NilClass' errors.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my errors and my code. Now I only have 2 failures. I am almost there! What else could possibly be wrong?? Thank you so much for the help thus far, PinnyM.

Comment: it says in chap. 9.2.2 to remove the like @user = User.find(params[:id])

Comment: @MicahSherman Please put that in an answer and accept it for the benefit of others who may be having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For others who might run into this, UsersController is missing the following:

```
before_action :correct_user,    only: [:edit, :update]
```

This uses your method in the SessionsHelper and since it's done before edit and update `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in edit and update the same evaluation becomes superfluous.